# Запрос SELECT выполняется долго, MySQL перебирает больше строк чем нужно

Tags: mysql, select, explain

Есть таблица товаров (товаров больше 10млн), для каждого товара заданы ключ категории (catID) и порядковый номер товара в этой категории (numInCat):

```
CREATE TABLE `goods` (
    `id` INT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `catID` SMALLINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `numInCat` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `name` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,  
    # ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
    INDEX `catIDnumInCat` (`catID`, `numInCat`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Пример записи:

```
id=10352230
catID=67
numInCat=4936929
name='пакет с пупырышками'
...
```

Нужно выбрать 3 товара из категории catID=67 начиная с порядкового номера numInCat=4936929+1 по порядку numInCat:

```
SELECT id,name FROM `goods` WHERE catID=67 AND numInCat>4936929 LIMIT 3
```

Этот запрос выполняется за 1 секунду, что очень долго для интернет-магазина.
Оператор EXPLAIN показывает, что индекс catIDnumInCat используется, но перебираются 3086114 записей! (key=catIDnumInCat,rows=3086114)

Если же запрос изменить на:

```
SELECT id,name FROM `goods` WHERE catID=67 AND numInCat>4936929 AND numInCat<=4936929+3 LIMIT 3
```

То он выполняется мгновенно. При это согласно оператору EXPLAIN, перебирается 3 записи.

Но запрос в таком виде не подходит, так как товары с numInCat=4936930,4936931,4936932 могут быть просто удалены ранее.

Вопрос: почему первый мой запрос SELECT перебирает так много строк базы данных? Индекс catIDnumInCat ведь построен и используется.

Использовать ORDER BY catID,numInCat пробовал - безрезультатно. Да и эта конструкция если на ошибаюсь работает уже после получения результата.

Comment: легче ответить почему второй запрос перебирает всего три записи)

Comment: Без order by кстати запрос вообще не гарантирует что даст именно следующие 3 записи, а не какие нибудь подошедшие по условию. Посмотрите в обоих explain поле key_len оно в обоих случаях одинаково и равно суммарной длине двух полей в индексе ? P.S. вообще конечно поведение очень странное, можно попробовать сделать `select id, name from ... where id in(select id from ... where catid.. numincat... order by ... limit 3)`, иногда такое помогает оптимизатору

Comment: для первого запроса key_len =2 для второго 5

Comment: @Ruport Вот этого я и боялся, он в первом случае решает из индекса только первое поле использовать. А почему, это загадка и тут только один ответ может быть "это MySQL ...". Мое предложение с подзапросом то же не помогает ?

Comment: нет. Сам подзапрос (ни чем не отличается от моего первого запроса, только удалением name из выборки) перебирает 3086114 записей. Да и LIMIT не допускается в скобках для IN - ругается MySQL.